# Why is Symfony 3.3.13 source generating a deprecation warning (not in my code)?

Tags: symfony, deprecation-warning

I am getting a deprecation notice in my Symfony 3.3.13 full-stack application.

> Autowiring-types are deprecated since Symfony 3.3 and will be removed
>   in 4.0. Use aliases instead for "Psr\Log\LoggerInterface".

Note that this is coming from Symfony source, not my code.

Clicking "Show Trace" shows that it is in file vendor/symfony/monolog-bundle/DependencyInjection/MonologExtension.php.

The code is:

```
if (method_exists('Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition', 'addAutowiringType')) {
         $container->getDefinition('monolog.logger')->addAutowiringType('Psr\Log\LoggerInterface');
    }
```

I suspect that I need to update the monolog-bundle version in my composer.json file, but haven't been able to figure out the correct version. It is currently set to "~2.8".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay. I finally thought to check Packagist for more recent monolog-bundle versions.

I changed the version in my composer.json file from "~2.8" to "~3.1" and did a composer update symfony/monolog-bundle.

Problem solved.

Comment: Well this is Jannes answer then.

Answer (score 6):

This is a notice that symfony autowiring has changed. [Symfony Autowiring](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html)

This is just a warning, your **symfony/monolog-bundle** anyway checks to see if autowiring-types exists:

```
if (method_exists('Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition', 'addAutowiringType')) {
```

Your version of Symfony just kept **addAutowiringType** function of [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/9b0226340705f75fd0cebd220746a36050ead8a9/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Definition.php) to give you this warning.

The latest release of Monolog bundle adds the necessary alias [github link](https://github.com/symfony/monolog-bundle/commit/28808a46ddb61f74c476068a15e75e254d3a8c2d#diff-7fa62223afe833e4f70f9e960111b353)

You can use version **3.1** of **monolog-bundle**.

**If for any reason you have to use any of the previous versions**, you will need to **add the alias** yourself in your services config.

```
services:
   Psr\Log\LoggerInterface: "@logger"
```